# I signed up for a new site and it got added under "Your Communities"

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stack-exchange-button, communities-list

I just signed up for an account on Ask Different. After some time, I noticed that Ask Different got automatically added to my personalized list of Communities in the site switcher.

As I had personalized the list, there shouldn't be any automated changes taking place.

---

This is getting *very* annoying. I have been looking at some sites which I reached via the Hot Network Questions. Some of the content is interesting/good and I want to vote/comment. To do that I need to create an account (which happens *fairly* frequently). As soon as I do that, the site gets added to my *manually* created list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was originally intentional.

However, we talked it over again and as of next build (`2014.3.12.2047` on MSO, `2014.3.12.1449` elsewhere) we won't be automatically appending new sites you join to your custom list.

Comment: You mean it won't be appended to *personalized* lists or it won't be appended *at all* (even to the automatic/default list)?

Comment: @AsheeshR Personalized lists. It can/will/should appear on the default list, especially for people with fewer than 5 site profiles.